# How to set link_to to another routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named Exercise, inside Exercise model i created new routes

```
get 'workout_lists' => 'exercises#workout_list', as: :workout_list
```

So, in my exercise folder, i have file named workout_list.html.erb ( in this folder i put a list of all my workout)

But i got problem when i put link_to edit in this folder

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_exercise_path(@exercise) %>
```

I got this error

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"exercises", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Looks like the `@exercise` in the argument of the `link_to` is nil. Did you set `@exercise` in `ExercisesController workout_list` method?

Comment: "I have a model named Exercise, inside Exercise model i created new routes". You did what now? Routes in Rails are defined in `config/routes.rb`  and have nothing to do with your models. As this is a simple nil error I would guess that the controller action you though was running is not. Add the logs which show what request was actually made and a complete example with the controller.